# Postgres groupBy not working with Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel, group-by, distinct, laravel-backpack

I am using Laravel Backpack with Postgres. I am wanting to groupBy (or distinct?) by a column to limit the list view. I have a single table that I want to groupBy `thread_id`. My latest attempt has been something like this:

```
$this->crud->groupBy('thread_id');
```

That code returns the error:

```
message: "SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR:  column "messages.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function       
(SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "messages" where "to_user_id" = 2 or "from_user_id" = 2 group by "thread_id" order by "thread_id" desc, "created_at" desc)"
```

Has anyone ran into this issue, specifically with Backpack?

Comment: Try `$this->crud->groupBy('thread_id', "messages.created_at");`